# How are users' top tags sorted in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, profile-page, users

Every user profile on Stack Overflow has a section that shows his top tags (see picture below).

[image: top tags]

However, this list is in a different order if we look at the complete tags list (picture below).

[image]

My question is: How does Stack Overflow sort the tags that appear in the "Top Tags" section?

It doesn't seem to consider only score (centering would appear), neither only posts (jquery would appear first).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top tags shown on your profile page are selected from your top **9** tags by post count (excluding CW posts), then sorted by their tag score and the top 6 shown.

For the tags in your screenshot, `centering` has a post count of just 1. You didn't include more context and nearly 2 years later we wouldn't normally be able to reconstruct what the post counts would have been for the other tags, but there must have been *at least* two other tags for which this user had a higher post count.

I've created a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273820/determine-what-top-tags-are-shown-on-a-user-profile) that shows the tag scores and counts for a given user on a given site, where the top 9 tags by post count are considered (configurable, with a switch to enable counting Community Wiki posts too). The tags are then ranked by tag score, so the top 6 rows are those that are shown on your profile page.

The screenshot in your question must be for [koala_dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2049063/koala-dev) (given that they are the only user with a [2k [`centering`] answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3/18153551#18153551)). Their relative tag rankings have not changed in the intervening time, nor have they created any new posts since 2016, so even if their tag scores have changed, the [query output for this user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273820/determine-what-top-tags-are-shown-on-a-user-profile?userid=2049063) is still interesting and illustrative of what happened here (numbers as per most recent SEDE refresh relative to this answer, 2020-08-09):

- They have 89 posts with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) making it their 6th tag by post count.
- They have 22 posts with [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter) and 22 posts with [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax), tied for
  8th place by count.
- [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3) is ranked 7th by count. Because it made the cut, it is ranked 3rd by tag score, pushing out [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) from their profile page Top Tags.
- They have 207 tags in total, 136 of these have 2 or more posts, these *all* would have to be considered before `centering` would be looked at.

All this ensures that answers in less-relevant tags don't define your profile top tag listing.

(Do take into account that the SEDE data set updates only once every week, so may be stale. Also, the tag scores shown on profiles are updated once a day at a different time from the SEDE data set refresh, creating another source of discrepancies. The query is a good approximation but don't expect exact results for accounts with active post and score count changes).

---

*This same question came up on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352838/how-are-the-top-tags-on-the-profile-page-selected) this weekend, so I've re-visited the algorithm.*