# How is the top tag determined?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

On [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830093/daniel-turcich?tab=profile) currently it shows Angular as my top tag, but when I view the *Activity* tab of my profile it shows Node.js as having a higher score.

Is Node.js exempted from being a top tag and Angular is not so it defaults to Angular? Or does it take into account the question score as well?

I'm not really sure and can't seem to find much here on meta.

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): [How are users' top tags sorted in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373829/1364007)

Comment: Number of posts?

Comment: As of right now, it shows [tag:electron] as your top tag, still with [tag:node.js] as the first tag on your Tags tab. This seems to agree with [Martijn's SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273820/determine-what-top-tags-are-shown-on-a-user-profile) from the proposed duplicate.